# Make Counter.most_common return dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-collections

I used the sample from the documentation:

```
>>> Counter('abracadabra').most_common(3)
[('a', 5), ('r', 2), ('b', 2)]
```

How can I make the result to be:

```
{ 'a': 5, 'r' :2 , 'b' :2}
```

supposing that we want to keep the `Counter().most_common()` code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#func-dict) will do this easily:

```
>>> dict(Counter('abracadabra').most_common(3))
{'a': 5, 'r': 2, 'b': 2}
>>>
```

For further reference, here is part of what is returned by `help(dict)`:

```
     dict(iterable) -> new dictionary initialized as if via:
 |      d = {}
 |      for k, v in iterable:
 |          d[k] = v
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to simply use `dict()`

```
dict(Counter('abracadabra').most_common(3))
```

Output:

```
{'a': 5, 'r': 2, 'b': 2}
```